# Embed Tinyletter into Pelican blog as form field

Tags: html, forms, email, jinja2, pelican

This is a question for [Tinyletter](https://tinyletter.com/) and [Pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/) but it is probably applicable to any static blog with a templating system.

Currently the only way to embed Tinyletter into a static blog is to use a button as a pop-up to this code:

```
<form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;" action="https://tinyletter.com/test-user" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('https://tinyletter.com/test-user', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600');return true"><p><label for="tlemail">Enter your email address</label></p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email" id="tlemail" /></p><input type="hidden" value="1" name="embed"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /><p><a href="https://tinyletter.com" target="_blank">powered by TinyLetter</a></p></form>
```

I tried to embed this code into my Jinja2 Pelican template file with this code:

```
<form class="" action="https://tinyletter.com/test-user" method="POST">
              <input class="" type="text" name="_replyto" placeholder="Subscribe via email" id="email">
          <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Send">
            Sign up
          </button>
</form>
```

After generating it, the form field displays and the button displays. But when I test the input by adding an email address (a working one, not a throwaway that tinyletter might reject), it takes me to: https://tinyletter.com/test-user/subscribe/validate and after passing the captcha it always gives the same error:

> That email doesn't look right. Please try again.

I tried to enter the same email on the https://tinyletter.com/test-user/subscribe/validate page and that works.

Is there something in the pop-up code that I need to include in my `form` code?